# Why did mine mapping a string to Map (Kotlin) go wrong

Tags: string, kotlin, mapping

I have a map `dataMap` that contains a map converted to a string `currentSessionData` as one of its values. I need the string `currentSessionData` to be mapped back to a map, which I tried to do like this:

```
    private fun loadData() {
        val directory = File(this.filesDir, "savefiles")
        if (directory.exists()) {
            Files.walk(Paths.get(directory.toString())).filter { Files.isRegularFile(it) }.forEach {
                var data = it.inputStream().readBytes().toString(Charsets.UTF_8)    
                val dataMap = JSONObject(data).toMap()
                Log.d("datamap", dataMap.toString())
                val currentSessionData = dataMap["sessionData"] 
                val map = currentSessionData!!.split(",").associate {
                    val (left, right) = it.split("=")
                    left to right
                }
                Log.d("mymap", map.toString())
            }
        }
    }
```

However, when I write the result to my log, I see this: `{{name=2023-07-08 18:32:03,  dateAndTime=2023-07-08 18:32:05,  time=871,  distance=18,  setsNumber=10,  arrowsPer=3,  type=target,  place=emptyPlace,  numOfArchers=1}}` and I am unable to access the keys and values because of the double parentheses. What is causing them and how can I get rid of them and have a map?

Comment: Your question is quite unclear as it is now. What's in the initial JSON (`data`)? What does the string value of `sessionData` look like in this JSON? Is it itself JSON? What did you print in your log? Is it the `currentSessionData` variable? Or of the resulting `map`? Or something else? How did you print it? Did you use `toString` or some serialization lib?

Comment: But why did you store `sessionData` as a string instead of a JSON object representing the map?

Comment: I stored it using FileOutputStrem, specifically ```val outputStream =FileOutputStream(file)
outputStream.write(myJson.toString().toByteArray())``` where `myJson` is the JSONObject. Converting `myJson` to byte array without the .toString() call gives me a receiver type mismatch, that's why I stored it as string.

Comment: I know it's messy, but it's my first time storing and saving data in Kotlin, so I am just trying to find some way to make it work.

Comment: No I don't mean the whole thing, but just the `sessionData` that you initially put in your JSON as a string. Why not use a proper reversible format and just insert it in the JSON like other fields? (`toString` is really not a good idea to serialize a map!)

Comment: I don't think I did, I put the `sessionData` into my JSON as a mutable map. I realize using `toString` is not a good idea, but I was pretty lost and just desperately trying to find a way lol

Comment: In any case, I'm not trying to be condescending or anything, just trying to inform you :) Make sure you check out JSON serialization libraries

Comment: No worries, I am glad for your advice. I have tons to learn and someone reviewing my code and pointing out the mistakes and bad practises is very helpful for me :)

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with JSON, you should *really* consider using a serialization library. Parsing by hand is rarely useful, and *very* error-prone. In Kotlin, I would suggest [Kotlinx Serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization), or Moshi, or if you really must, maybe Jackson.

Now, as to your current problem, you're printing `map` with `toString`, which by default prints a comma-separated list of `key=value`, surrounded by braces. What you're seeing is just the first key (`{name`) and last value (`1}`) respectively starting and ending with braces, so it looks like double-braces.

This is because your parsing code didn't take into account the fact that the string `currentSessionData` itself is surrounded by braces (you haven't shared it, but that's my informed guess), probably because you initially serialized it using `Map`'s default `toString` method too. This is a pretty bad idea, as it is not a reversible operation. You should instead use a real JSON encoding for the map (e.g. encode it as a JSON object).

The code is fixable (by removing those braces when parsing the string into a map), but please don't go this route.

Also, there are plenty of little things you could improve in your code here:

- `File(this.filesDir, "savefiles")` -> `filesDir.resolve("savefiles")`
- `Paths.get(directory.toString())` -> `directory.toPath()`
- `it.inputStream().readBytes().toString(Charsets.UTF_8)` -> `it.readText()`

Comment: Okay, thank you for your detailed answer and all advice provided. I will try to look into serialization more and refactor my code as whole.